# How to run a command on remote host from a service?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line

I have a service in '/etc/init.d'. In that service, I run a command on a remote machine using ssh as a user. Currently I do this in the following way:

```
sudo -u user bash -c "ssh user@172.21.6.70 'source ~/.envrc ; (cd /catalog; ./bin/catalog start &)'"
```

This is the start command of that service and the service name is catalog.

When I do `sudo service catatlog start` the command runs successfully i.e it properly SSH'es into the target machine which is `user@172.21.6.70` as the user `user` but it does not start the service.

Can anyone tell me how to tweak this so that it runs successfully?

Comment: @muru - I deleted the question from askubuntu and I think now you can re-open this one.

Comment: The question has now been reopened.

Comment: @terdon thank you. I will post the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it by using `nohup` command:

```
sudo -iu user ssh user@172.21.6.70 "nohup bash -c 'source ~/.envrc ; (cd /catalog; ./bin/catalog start &)'"
```